# If the UK Prime Minister dies who is "next in line" given there is no current deputy PM

Tags: united-kingdom, prime-minister

"Because of this there is not always a sitting Deputy Prime Minister. This means that it is up to the Prime Minister to choose whether or not he/she wants to have a deputy. The position was created in 1942 and Clement Attlee was the first Deputy Prime Minister. There has been no Deputy Prime Minister since 2015." - [Simple wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom)

Boris Johnson has [just been admitted to hospital due to COVID-19](https://www.politico.eu/article/boris-johnson-admitted-to-hospital-with-covid-19/). It feels logical that it should be someone high up within the Conservative party, but I don't know who it would be / what position and a quick search for this didn't yield any results.

Comment: @Polygnome I guess my question might be more of an addition than a separate question - its essentially the same question though I mention that we have no deputy PM and the developing hospitalisation raises the stakes of it all

Answer (score 1):

Prime ministers with no deputy often appoint a First Secretary of State.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Secretary_of_State

This is Dominic Raab at the time of writing. He is chairing the cabinet for now. Some prime ministers have both.